# Subdomain pointing to multiple Vercel NextJS apps

Tags: reactjs, next.js, dns, subdomain, vercel

Is it possible to host a custom domain inside vercel, and have different subdomains point to multiple nextjs apps.

For example
[www.example.com](http://www.example.com) -> NextJS App 1
blog.example.com -> NextJS App 2

My understand is subdomains have to point to specific ip addresses, or another url.

I would like 2 completely separate codebases for my www and blog React applications.

Comment: Or thinking out loud, I simply create a cname record and point it to the internal vercel app link? Eg blog.example.com -> my-cool-app.vercel.app